# Can we logon as a full windows profile using ansible

Tags: windows, automation, ansible, winrm

I know that Ansible uses winRM to connect to window hosts, which means it does not fully load a windows profile when connecting to a host, but rather can execute bat/powershell commands remotely.

But is there a method where I can logon as a complete Windows profile using Ansible.

My requirement is that every Monday morning I want an automated job (Preferrabley Jenkins ->  Ansible) that will logon to my Windows Server machines (around 10 machines). Currently we have a support team that does this every Monday morning (because the machines are rebooted every weekend), and sometimes 1 or 2 machines are missed out, and I would like to automate this because we have Scheduled Tasks that are supposed to run early in the morning, that sometimes misses to run because support forgets to login to a particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 connection plugins for Windows in Ansible [PSRP](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/psrp_connection.html) and [WinRM](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/winrm_connection.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-winrm-connection). Whatever tasks your support team is performing manually can be automated with [Ansible Windows Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/index.html) or Powershell commands. Though they are executed remotely, actions are performed on the target servers only.

Comment: I am already performing tasks on my Windows server using Ansible via WinRM (downloading code from artifactory, deploying modules..etc). While I am aware these are possible, I want to know if it is possible to do a full Windows logon that loads the complete profile. If the machine is signed out I know it can still connect to the machine and persomr win_copy...etc, but I want the system to be completely logged on

Comment: You mean all the startup tasks, profile defaults loaded and all delayed services started, Like it happens in GUI Logon ?

Comment: yes exactly :) is that possible?

Comment: no, it is not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no connection plugin to perform an interactive (GUI) login.

For people who need an interactive login for a user at least once so that it has a fully created profile ([community.windows.win_user_profile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_user_profile_module.html) will not do it completely, e. g. shell bag for the desktop will still be missing in the registry), you can use the following workaround:

1. Configure [automatic logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon) temporarily for that user.
2. Reboot the machine. The user will login automatically and interactively.
3. Disable automatic logon again.
4. Reboot the machine. After that, the user has a fully created profile.